# Select parent sibling directory to upload file in PHP

Tags: php, directory

Main directory of file upload page is `C:\xampp\htdocs\site\admin\upload_data` where my upload.php is stored and in this file the path is `upload/`, how can I change this path to `C:\xampp\htdocs\site\user\Image\article_images`. In my code target directory is

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
```

Comment: Am I understanding correctly? You have that assignment line and want to change it? Why don't you?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

This will help.

```
$target_dir = "../../user/Image/article_images/";
```